# How to combine multiple condition in table join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Simply speaking, I two rule tables, one lists all the rules, the other lists details of the rules:

```
Rule_ID Rule_Name 
1      "Rule Name 1"
2      "Rule Name 2"

Target_Rule_ID Condition
1              >10
1              <20
1              !=15
1              !=18
2              >30
```

Meaning:  for Rule_ID number 1, the value is more than 10, less then 20, and not eqaul to 15 nor 18.

I need to apply this rule to another data table, like:

```
ID    Value 
1     11
2     60
3     15
```

And make the result like:

```
ID   Value   Rule_ID
1    11      1
2    60      2
3    15      null
```

The current method I can think of is use a high level language like python.

1. get the rules all out
2. make the where clause
3. join the table one by one

But sounds inefficient, since that means I need to join the rule with the data table X times (X = total rule number).

I wonder is there a better way to do this directly in sql server? Any suggestions?

(Also assume the rules don't conflict with each other, that would make the problem even harder)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of where you do it, you need a way to separate the numerical value from its rule expression (condition, like <10 etc). Have you thought about separating expressions and values?

Something like

```
rule_details table:  

t_rule_id rule_type Value
1         >         10
1         <         20
```

joining that set to the set of information to be checked/validated. With a lot of case statements

```
case 
    when rule_type = '>' and value > other_value then true
    when rule_type = '>' and value <= other_value then false
    ...
end as rule_satisfied
```

you can create a column to validate each number against the criteria set out in the rule details. At that point you can do a logical AND on each group created -> if TRUE then all rules satisfied.